# How to create an efficient database design in sql using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

Right now I'm still a beginner in databases and still learning all about it. I have a problem with the design of my database and I don't really know where to go from here. Basically I'm building a music store website that has guitars and bass as products. Now, I have a total of six brands in my database, including its corresponding logo images for displaying in a webpage. Both guitar and bass can use this database for retrieving the needed brand.

brandId  name  image

1         Ibanez    xyz.jpg

2         Fender    abc.jpg

3         Gibson    hjk.jpg

4         PRS        wyx.jpg

5         Musicman cde.jpg

6         ESP        ihl.jpg

Now, I would display those brands for guitar using asp repeater. In this case, the guitar webpage has no problem displaying all the brands because it has all products for that brand. Here is the aspx code for the guitar:

```
<asp:Content ID='Content1' ContentPlaceHolderID='ContentPlaceHolder1' Runat='Server'>

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound" ItemType="brand" SelectMethod="GetBrandData"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="one-third">
            <div>
             <asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton" OnClick="Repeater1_OnClick" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Item.brandId %>'>
                 <asp:Image ID="brandImage" runat="server" height="250px" width="300px" />
             </asp:LinkButton>
            </div>

        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

And here is the code-behind for the guitar:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = e.Item.FindControl("brandImage") as Image;
    img.ImageUrl = "../Images/Brands/" + ((brand)e.Item.DataItem).image;
}

public List<brand> GetBrandData()
{
    MusicStoreDBEntities obj = new MusicStoreDBEntities();
    List<brand> list = new List<brand>();
    list = (from g in obj.brands select g).ToList();

    return list;

}
```

Meanwhile the bass can only display three brands which is Ibanez,Fender and Musicman. This is where the problem starts. It basically has the same aspx code as the guitar but I've made this change to the sql query so that it can return only those three brands.

```
public List<brand> GetBrandData()
{
    MusicStoreDBEntities obj = new MusicStoreDBEntities();
    List<brand> list = new List<brand>();
    list = (from g in obj.brands where g.name=="Ibanez"||g.name=="Fender"||g.name=="Musicman" select g).ToList();

    return list;

}
```

I have multiple where clauses in that query so that i can just retrieve those three brands. I really feel like this is not the most efficient way and will cause problems if lets say, i wanted to add a seventh brand and I would need that to display on the bass webpage, then i would need to manually edit query everytime, which is not ideal. I wanted to know if there are other solutions for managing the query or solutions for the design aspect of the database.

I hope you guys can give me some input on this.

Comment: Add column in table InstrumentType. Add unique value for each type of instrument (1=Guitar, 2=Bass, 3=Qitar, 4=Ukelele, 5=Berimbau etc.). Now filter on InstrumentType. Possibly want to make a separate table to maintain these values and join your query if you intend to add new types in the future.

Comment: You do not want to hardcode the brands like this. You want to have an instrument table. In that table you would have a column for instrument type. Additionally you would have a column for Brand. Then you would query your data on the bass page and find all brands for instruments with a type of bass. You certainly don't want to create a new page for each instrument type. That is not a good way to deal with data or coding. You need to make your logic expandable so that you don't need to do anything for new instrument types.

Comment: @SeanLange - but what if a brand has both types? like for example a brand called "Ibanez" is both guitar and bass. Can I specify it in my database like this Type Brand | Guitar Ibanez | Bass Ibanez? Is it okay to repeat the brands?

Comment: Why would you. If your instrument table has a column for Brand and another column for Type you are in good shape. You need to separate the data points and not mix things like brand and type into one piece of information. Those are two distinct pieces of data.

Comment: Yes, thats what i think i meant on my reply. For example, Row 1 has Type = Guitar and Brand = Ibanez. Then Row 2 has Type = Bass and Brand = Ibanez so on so forth. Type and Brand is actually separate columns. Is my analysis on your comment correct? If not, please provide a simple example for me to follow. Sorry if im slow in getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my database Design

```
CREATE TABLE Brands
(
BrandID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT Pk_Brands Primary Key
,Beandname Varchar(200)
)


CREATE TABLE InstrumentType
(
InstrumentTypeID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT Pk_InstrumentType Primary Key
,InstrumentName Varchar(200)
)


CREATE TABLE Products
(
ProductsID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT Pk_Products Primary Key
,BrandID INT 
,InstrumentTypeID INT
,ProductImage Varchar(100)
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Products__Brands] FOREIGN KEY([BrandID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Brands] ([BrandID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_InstrumentTypesID] FOREIGN KEY([InstrumentTypeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[InstrumentType] ([InstrumentTypeID])
GO
```

Intial Sample Data

```
INSERT INTO Brands (Beandname)
SELECT 'Ibanez' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fender' UNION ALL
SELECT 'PRS'    UNION ALL
SELECT 'ESP'    UNION ALL
SELECT 'Warwick'

Go
INSERT INTO InstrumentType(InstrumentName)

SELECT 'Guitar'    UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bass' 

INSERT INTO Products(InstrumentTypeID,BrandID,ProductImage)

SELECT 1 , 1,'xyz.jpg' UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 1,'hyz.jpg' UNION ALL
SELECT 1 , 2,'abc.jpg' UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 2,'fgh.jpg' UNION ALL
SELECT 1 , 3,'yui.jpg' UNION ALL
SELECT 1 , 4,'mbm.jpg' UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 5,'omo.jpg'

SELECT * FROM Brands 
SELECT * FROM InstrumentType 
SELECT * FRom Products
```

Get the Result by using below Query

```
SELECT 
 p.ProductsID
--,p.BrandID
,B.Beandname
--,p.InstrumentTypeID
,i.InstrumentName
,p.ProductImage

FROM Products P
INNER JOIN Brands B
    On B.BrandID=p.BrandID
INNER JOIN InstrumentType I
    On I.InstrumentTypeID=P.InstrumentTypeID
```

Insert Data Into Product Table BY Passing Parameters in to the below Sp

```
CREATE Procedure Usp_Products_Insert
(
@InstrumentTypeID INT,
@BrandID INT,
@ProductImage VARCHAR(100)
)           
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
            WHERE TABLE_NAME='Products'
        )
    Begin
        INSERT INTO Products(
                    InstrumentTypeID,
                    BrandID,
                    ProductImage)
        SELECT @InstrumentTypeID,
                @BrandID,
                @ProductImage
    END

END

EXEC Usp_Products_Insert @InstrumentTypeID=1
                        ,@BrandID=2
                        ,@ProductImage='TTTT.Jpg'

SELECT * FRom Products
```

Comment: Wow this is a very interesting design for me.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all you are storing, you can add an extra two fields in the database
One called Guitar and has a 1 when the brand applies to a guitar (so all of them at the moment) and another field called Bass which only has a 1 on the brands which uses a bass.

In your filter you can add "where g.Bass==1"

This will only return the Bass brands.

However, if you intend to expand on the instruments, you should create a separate table which links the type of instrument to the brands.

eg

Type   Brand
Guitar 1
Guitar 2
Guitar 3
Guitar 4
etc
Bass   1
Bass   2
Bass   5

Then link the two tables together in the where.